# ruamel.yaml some comments get lost in round_trip_dump()

Tags: yaml, ruamel.yaml

The code below reproduces the issue:

```
from ruamel.yaml import round_trip_load, round_trip_dump, YAML
import sys

obj = round_trip_load('''\
a: 1  # comment for a
b:  # comment for b
  c: 2  # comment for c
''')

print('-------------------------- YAML().dump(obj, sys.stdout)')
YAML().dump(obj, sys.stdout)

print('-------------------------- print(round_trip_dump(obj))')
print(round_trip_dump(obj))
```

Output

```
-------------------------- YAML().dump(obj, sys.stdout)
a: 1  # comment for a
b:  # comment for b
  c: 2  # comment for c
-------------------------- print(round_trip_dump(obj))
a: 1
b:  # comment for b
  c: 2
```

You can see that `YAML().dump(obj, sys.stdout)` correctly prints the comments, but `print(round_trip_dump(obj))` loses `comment for a` and `comment for c`.

If you run it in debug mode, you can see `obj.ca.items` correctly keep the comments.

Therefore I believe it is a bug in `round_trip_dump()`.

I was going to create a ticket for the project, but the instruction asked me to post here first, to clarify that it is not a faulty usage of the library.

Is it a bug?  Or my misusage?

The [document](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html#output-of-dump-as-a-string) asks why output of dump() as a string is necessary.

Because I want to convert the object into a string and save as VARCHAR in database.

Thank you in advance.

Environment: ruamel.yaml==0.17.21 with Python 3.11 on 64 bit Windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely falls under misusage. The documentation you refer to explains why a new API was needed,and you
combine `round_trip_dump`/`round_trip_load` from the old API with a `YAML()` instance from the new API
and expect things to work, which they don't ( otherwise a new API would probably not have
been necessary ). Don't use the old API, for any new projects.

If you have a streaming API (like the one currently in `ruamel.yaml`) you can easily grab the output,
using an `io.BytesIO()` buffer:

```py
import sys
import io
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a: 1  # comment for a
b:  # comment for b
  c: 2  # comment for c
"""
    
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.preserve_quotes = True
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
buf = io.BytesIO()  # yamp.dump generates a stream of utf-8/bytes 
yaml.dump(data, buf)
yaml_out = buf.getvalue().decode("utf-8")
print(f'here is the streamed output:\n{yaml_out}')
```

which gives:

```
here is the streamed output:
a: 1  # comment for a
b:  # comment for b
  c: 2  # comment for c
```

So stick with the new API as it is trivial to convert the output of a stream based API to a string yourself.

Interpreting a stream parameter with a default value `None` as
"return as a string" is IMO not the right thing to built in the (new) API. In the same
way that e.g. Python's `datatime.date()` constructor creates an object and **doesn't have** an option to `stream` built in
(so you can't do `datetime.date(2023, 4, 18, stream=sys.stdout)` ), even though I can image there
is someone out there that might want to do that.

(tested on macOS and Linux, but it should work on Windows)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Do you consider providing two functions `ruamel.yaml.obj_to_yaml_string(obj)` and `ruamel.yaml.yaml_string_to_obj(yaml_string)` ?  I see many people have such requirements.  Otherwise everyone has to write same code again and again.

Comment: I found in your answer, using `io.StringIO` instead of `io.BytesIO` is more convenient.  Just `getvalue()` and don't need to `.decode()`.

Comment: `yaml.dump()` dumps a bytes stream, you can of course convert that in different ways to a Python string. Since I assumed VARCHAR store utf-8 as well (and certainly not a Python string) conversion to string and back should not be efficient.

Comment: I don't see the advantage of `ruamel.yaml.yaml_string_to_obj(yaml_string)`, it is more typing than `ruamel.yaml.YAML().load(yaml_string)` that you can do now. Having a  `YAML()` instance is going to be more crucial in the future for persisting information, so there are not going to be new module level functions and the existing ones are going away.

Comment: Now I see `YAML().load()` provide the first part, and I only need `obj_to_yaml_string(obj)`.  pyYaml has `yaml_string = yaml.dump(obj)`.  I thought `ruamel.yaml.round_trip_dump(obj)` was what I wanted.  Eventuall I have to code it by myself.  It's not too complicated.  I can just do it.  Thank you for your patience and kind answers.